# Hide the Finder sidebar permanently

Tags: macos, finder

I've Googled for this a little bit, and I wasn't able to find an obvious answer, so is it possible to hide the Finder sidebar completely? So that it never comes back until I tell it to? The same goes for the toolbar.

Thanks for any help you can provide. :)

Extra info:

- I am using OS X Mountain Lion on this Mac.

Comment: Hide it just for a certain window?  Or for all future windows?  Or for all windows created in the past as well?

Comment: I would like to hide it for absolutely everything, no matter the day it is, or was, open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ShowSidebar -bool false; killall Finder
```

`ShowToolbar -bool false` didn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) So this would make it automatically never appear again?

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't seem to affect some special folders like trash.

Comment: not works on elcapitan

Comment: Not working on 10.12

Comment: This no longer seems to work. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FinderMinder](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs#finderminder). In preferences check Run AppleScript, click edit and add this line

```
set toolbar visible to false
```

Comment: I cannot find “Preferences” or “Run AppleScript” in the current version of FinderMinder.

Answer (score 1):

**FinderMinder is the answer**... with some deeper explanation.

Download here: [FinderMinder](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) `http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/`

**Setup Instructions**

In FinderMinder's "Contents" (right click the app, select "Show Package Contents") you will find a "Contents" folder.  Open that, then open "Resources" then you will see a file "com.apple.finder.scpt".

Open com.apple.finder.scpt in the native "Script Editor" app.  Delete the `(*` and the `*)`, change the `set toolbar visible to true` to `set toolbar visible to false`, then save the script.  Now run FinderMinder and set it up normally to allow it to control the Finder through the System Preferences.  Voila!

**Visual Setup**

[image]
[image]
[image]

On and off for years I have I have been searching for a way to remove the Finder's sidebars and toolbars, never to show again.  Unfortunately the "bar" epidemic became a pandemic with Catalina which randomly likes to re-show sidebars and toolbars on windows where they were turned off. Finder has been a hot-mess since the inception of Mac OS X and FinderMinder provides some serious relief from the highly frustrating experience of Mac OS X Finder. (FTFF)

Props to @1.61803 for the original FinderMinder tip, you are my freekin' hero! This might be the best Christmas gift for me for 2019!

Comment: Those are some really cool arrows! :) On a side note: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205300/313842 Both seem to work similarly internally.

Answer (score 0):

Open Finder, both options are in the View menu.

```
View -> Hide Sidebar
```

For the Status bar,

```
View -> Hide Status Bar
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it appears again by re-opening the folder. lol BTW, I don't want to hide the sidebar.

Comment: ahh, odd functionality.  creating an new window in Finder using cmd+N opens a new window with the Sidebar hidden, but opening a new window by double clicking opens a new window with the sidebar... odd

Answer (score -1):

New Finder windows in Mountain Lion appear to behave as in previous versions:

Create a new Finder window in any manner--Command-N, click on Finder in dock, etc. Adjust this window as to screen location, size, view style--everything customizable. Close the window -- and all future new Finder windows will be exactly as you have set.